Could an automotive 24V/10A relay without a flyback diode be burned out?
I'm a junior EE working on a complaint from a client. Our machines are designed such that when you activate the remote control an internal relay switches the incoming interlock signal from a steering wheel (terminal 30)[†], which is no more than 0.5[mA]. The relay coil (terminal 86) is supplied by a 24V "remote on" signal from the radio reciever transistor outputs, whos max cont. current output is 3[A]. There is no flyback diode present on either the coil or contacts.
[†] Terminals 86, 85 and 30 (DIN 72552) refer to the positive and negative supply to the coil.
This client complains that every few months this relay burns on terminals 86 and 85, even after he replaces it with 40A relay. After looking through the schematics and relay product there is no flyback diode in the relay or in the harness. Could this logically be a cause of the clients issue?
Burnt relay in question: Sima WM630-24C
Radio Reciever: PN-R17-1
Burnt relay rotated

"Burnt" Relay

Resistance over terminals 86 and 85


Hi. The diode is to protect the circuit, not the relay. Which part of the relay is burned? Coil or the contacts?

What's the relay switching? As @Saadat asks, how does the relay fail? Welded closed or open, or is it a coil failure?

Why specify "automotive"?

Wow, thanks for the very fast replies. Unfortunately I can't be present for inspection (different continent) but terminals 86 and 85 are burned. The relay is switching an interlock signal to a motor controller.

No flyback where, on the coil, or on switch contacts? What load the relay is switching? Inductive, capacitive, resistive? What voltages and currents are in question? What are terminals "86" and "85" called in real life?

No flyback on either coil or contacts. Relay is just switching to disable or enable an interlock signal. It's not entirely clear what the current is but the voltage is 24V. Terminals 86 and 85 (DIN 72552) refer to the positive and negative supply to the coil.

A "relay burning on [coil terminals]" does not exactly say much. Please get clear pictures from the client, and edit the question to add them in.

Also, a diode across the contacts is not always advisable, since you're a single failure away from the relay failing closed. A snubber would do a job the same or better, and would not have the ugly "fail shorted" failure mode since there are two quite different elements in series. Typically if the capacitor shorts out, the resistor will burn out and fail open rather than closed.

Which exact relay type, where is the datasheet which says how it needs to be used in order to not burn? It does not matter if it is a 40A or 100A  rated for switching, if it heats up too much when the coil is operated longer than allowed and the coil heats up and melts.

@Velvet The diode will do nothing if the coil heats up. Also, putting a diode over coil is worst possible solution that guarantees slower release of the switching contacts and may shorten the contact life.

@Justme "putting a diode over coil is worst possible solution". The worst possible solution would be to omit any kind of surge protection. There are other solutions, if the design specification requires them.

A 10A relay switching only 0.5mA? A mechanical switch requires a minimum’wetting’ current otherwise the contacts may oxidize and fail to make contact.  The idea of ‘burnt’ terminals seems suspicious to me. As reported, the failure makes no sense - need to get more evidence. You’ll probably find the reality is somewhat different to what was reported.

At this point I am also a bit dubious about the burnt terminals. The client sent photos which did not reveal any visible burn marks, I will upload them

Neither the terminals nor coil show obvious signs of over heating. Overheated terminals would be dull and bluish, an overheated coil is usually darker with uneven coloring. The ohmmeter appears to show the coil as open. This all would tend to indicate that either the coil was fused relatively quickly, or that the coil wire broke from vibration, typically where it attaches to the terminals.
If the coil is being burnt open quickly it would probably be getting some high voltage surges, so you could look at adding surge protection such as a TVS diode, and use a fuse in the coil circuit, maybe 2 A so that if the TVS diode shorts the wiring is protected.
If the coil wire is breaking, you could look at how the relay is mounted. Those relays are generally pretty resilient physically, but if you stress the terminals enough it could break the wire off.
A 40 A relay is overkill for this application, you should use one with contact ratings more in line with your load, a 1 A relay would probably be about right. Unfortunately, that style of relays is usually rated at at least 20 A, and small signal relays may not be rugged enough for automotive use.
As far as diodes across the coil, you can buy automotive relays with just the coil, with a built-in diode across the coil (you then have to be mindful of the polarity when you connect them) or with a built-in resistor across the coil (gives some flyback protection without being polarity sensitive).

Not also that in automotive applications you may have to worry about flyback from the starter motor and solenoid, which can push some pretty massive surges through any unprotected parts of the system.

Likely there is a diode in the control module driving the coil, and flyback is a non sequitur.  This can be verified by examining the drive circuit connected to the coil.  Follow the wiring harness, connector pinout, PCB traces, and identify component types.
Do you have supply voltage logging capability; is it possible the voltage is rising excessively?  If this is an automotive application, note that 24V load dump can reach almost 200V peak (see e.g. ISO 16750-2).  If this is a regular occurrence, perhaps designing in such a capability would be worth the effort.
If anything else fails on the system, at the same time, or here and there generally, and give or take what components may be active at any given time, that can help identify a potential common cause.


A great deal of automotive relays on the market are garbage. Sourcing sane ones can be a challenge.

Contrary to the popular belief, the flyback diode has to be there not only to protect the feeding citcuit. Relay coil itself can suffer from the 100-300V kick it makes on turn-off.


The usual failure mode thereof is that the insulation breaks by voltage, a part of the coil is shorted, the coil current goes up and the coil burns.
If a diode is not up to your taste (e.g way too slow turn off), a resistor, a capacitor, a combination of them or other flyback circuits can do the thing with various tradeoffs.

The relay is an automotive relay and for reliability and being able to decisively switch 40A loads, the coil requires a lot of power.
The coil is rated 1.6 watts to operate.
Please be sure to be adequately able to conduct the heat of the coil away, through the terminals or maybe by attaching the relay to large metal chassis from the provided tab - if you have the model with the tab.
So the 0.5mA load you are switching requires 66mA coil current at 24V.
Maybe switch to a small signal relay or photocoupler in order to not burn up the relay by keeping the coil powered.
The relay data sheet is very vague on details such as if it is acceptable to keep the coil on for extended periods of time and what is an acceptale temperature rise. So you don't need a beefier relay, on the contrary, beefier relays need more power for the coil and heat up more.
